Ordenar de forma ascendente con js dentro de un foreach
Tengo el siguiente mapper
class DatesCalendarMapper {
  map(responses) {
    let dates_quote = [];
    let dates_departure = [];
    let allReturnDates = [];
    let flag = true;
    responses.forEach((response) => {
      let dateParsed = new Date(response.DepartureDate);

      if (
        dates_quote.findIndex((item) => item.day === dateParsed.getUTCDate()) <
        0
      ) {
        let date_destination = {
          date: dateParsed,
          day: dateParsed.getUTCDate(),
          month: dateParsed.getMonth(),
        };
        dates_quote.push(date_destination);
      }

      let returnDate = new Date(response.ReturnDate);

      allReturnDates = responses.map((obj) => {
        let dayDate = new Date(obj.DepartureDate);
        let quouteResult = {
          date: dayDate,
          day: dayDate.getUTCDate(),
          month: dayDate.getMonth(),
          price: obj.Amount,
          airline: obj.Airline,
        };
        return quouteResult;
      });

      let lowestPrices = {};

      allReturnDates.forEach((item) => {
        if (
          !lowestPrices[item.day] ||
          item.price < lowestPrices[item.day].price
        ) {
          lowestPrices[item.day] = item;
        }
      });
      let resultFiltered = Object.values(lowestPrices).sort(
        (a, b) => a.month - b.month || a.day - b.day
      );

      let parsedResult = {
        date: returnDate,
        day: returnDate.getUTCDate(),
        month: returnDate.getMonth(),
        rates: resultFiltered,
      };
      dates_departure.push(parsedResult);
      flag = false;
    });

    const fligth = {
      dates_quote: dates_quote.sort(
        (a, b) => a.month - b.month || a.day - b.day
      ),
      dates_departure: dates_departure.sort(
        (a, b) => a.month - b.month || a.day - b.day
      ),
    };
    return fligth;
  }
}

export const datesCalendarMapper = new DatesCalendarMapper();

Pero cuando veo el resultado de esta linea no, me lo está ordenando de forma ascendente,
let resultFiltered = Object.values(lowestPrices).sort((a, b) => a.month - b.month || a.day - b.day);

pero eso sólo pasa cuando pongo la variable dentro del objeto parsedResult, si no pongo el resultado de resultFiltered  en parsedResult si se ordena de forma ascendente pero si lo pongo no se ordena, me lo deja como siempre.
Sabrán alguna razón o que me falta agregar para que si se quede el resultado ordenado.
Adjunto ejemplo de la data que le envío a este mapper
[
  {
    "DepartureDate": "2024-06-02T00:00:00",
    "ReturnDate": "2024-06-02T00:00:00",
    "Amount": 78390,
    "Airline": "P5",
    "Engine": 14
  },
  {
    "DepartureDate": "2024-06-03T00:00:00",
    "ReturnDate": "2024-06-03T00:00:00",
    "Amount": 78390,
    "Airline": "P5",
    "Engine": 14
  },
  {
    "DepartureDate": "2024-05-31T00:00:00",
    "ReturnDate": "2024-05-31T00:00:00",
    "Amount": 204980,
    "Airline": "P5",
    "Engine": 14
  },
  {
    "DepartureDate": "2024-06-01T00:00:00",
    "ReturnDate": "2024-06-01T00:00:00",
    "Amount": 238300,
    "Airline": "P5",
    "Engine": 14
  },
  {
    "DepartureDate": "2024-05-30T00:00:00",
    "ReturnDate": "2024-05-30T00:00:00",
    "Amount": 311870,
    "Airline": "AV",
    "Engine": 1
  }
]


Lo que veo es que tienes todo dentro del forEach de la línea 7 (responses.forEach) lo cual redefine allReturnDates y lowestPrices cada iteración. Por otro lado, puedes usar findIndex en dates_quote para que se detenga en cuanto encuentre una coincidencia si es lo que deseas.

No entiendo la pregunta, yo probé tu código y veo que los arrays rates correctamente ordenados por fecha

no, es que cuando lo prueba si lo ordena pero en el objeto final, no salen ordenados :(
